# WD15 dock incompatible with Arch Linux laptop

Tags: arch-linux, usb, ethernet, dock, dock-station

I've got a WD15 dock and a Dell laptop running Arch Linux.

I inserted two monitors' HDMI plugs into the dock and plugged the dock's USB-C cable into my laptop. The laptop display outputs correctly to the monitors.

I inserted the plug of a USB keyboard and mouse into the dock, but the laptop didn't detect them. I plugged an Ethernet cable into the dock, but the laptop did not detect that either.

What must I do to make the laptop detect the keyboard, mouse and Ethernet cable that are plugged into the WD15?

Comment: You should take a look at the UEFI settings (so before boot) about thunderbolt settings probably in a security menu. The linux documentation about this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/thunderbolt.html#security-levels-and-how-to-use-them

Comment: @A.B I'm not exactly sure about the step-by-step instructions I should do. I do not have the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules` on my machine, for example.

Comment: But did you look at your BIOS as was written in the first part of my comment?